# Set 'Following user or group can join to domain' permissions on computer object created in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, vmware

I have a VMWare View environment where we typically have to expand the pool occasionally by large numbers of computers.

For our environment to add a linked clone computer in a pool to the domain we have to pre-create the computer object in Active Directory and set the 'Following user or group can join to domain' permissions to a certain group temporarily. When you manually do this one computer at a time - you can set that permission using the GUI/Wizard.

I am trying to automate this by adding computers to Active Directory by a PowerShell script.  I have the script working and it adds the computer objects but I am not finding an obvious way to set those permissions either at the time of creating the computer object or modifying the permissions after creation.

How would I go about setting those permissions using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Two links:

[previous time this was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984869/set-the-following-user-or-group-can-join-to-a-domain-after-creating-the-comput)

[scripting guys forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ed0ee3d6-82cc-42a6-84d9-daa82832a916/powershell-select-usergroup-to-join-computer-in-domain?forum=ITCG)

There are four permissions (see the second link) that have to be set if you want to both limit domain joiners but allow a specific person to join a specific machine.

Another option would be to have a service account for View, which is in your GPO restricted Domain Joiners group.  Then you can restrict domain user accounts from joining the domain and just have the service account and your support techs with the right.  And the service account would automatically add every VM that it makes, using Add-Computer.

Comment: I had already read the previous time this was asked here and it didn't answer my question.  Neither does a VBScript way of doing it.  Thanks.  I am looking for help on the PowerShell command to edit those permissions.

Comment: @Ian. The first one shows you how to set the permissions in Powershell.  The second enumerates the permissions you need to set.  He even gives a clue:  _This probably can be done in PowerShell using the Get-Acl and Set-Acl cmdlets. I have not worked with these cmdlets yet, and it would take me awhile to convert the VBScript program. Perhaps someone else has used Set-Acl with AD objects and can help._

Answer (score 1):

Get-Acl and Set-Acl can do this, but it's not pretty. Non-AD access ACEs are pretty simple: you grant or deny permissions to a user/group/computer/etc, and you decide if the ACE is going to apply to the object and/or any of its children. AD aces can be that broad, too, but they can also have permissions granted or denied to certain properties, objects, extended rights, and validated rights (literally thousands of different things). Inheritance can also be locked down just to specific types of objects. You do that with GUIDs that you have to look up.

Going off of the link in the other answer, you need these four things granted:

- Reset Password
- Validated write to DNS host name
- Validated write to service principal name
- Write Account Restrictions

You need four separate ACEs to do that. The following code snippet shows how to do that, but it assumes you have the AD cmdlets and that you want to apply the ACEs to each computer object. It's possible to apply these ACEs to an OU that computer objects would inherit, but you'd need to change the inheritance and (optionally) the InheritedObjectType GUID. Anyway, try this:

```
$IdentityReference = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] "UserNameHere"
$ComputerDistinguishedName = Get-ADComputer ComputerNameHere | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName

$SD = Get-Acl "AD:\$ComputerDistinguishedName"


# Validated write to DNS host name
$SD.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule (
    $IdentityReference,
    "Self",  # Validated Write access mask ([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights])
    "Allow", # ACE type ([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType])
    "72e39547-7b18-11d1-adef-00c04fd8d5cd",  # GUID for 'Validated write to DNS host name'
    "None",  # ACE will only apply to the object it's assigned to ([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance])
    [guid]::Empty                            # Inherited object type (in this case in can apply to any objects)
)))

# Validated write to service principal name
$SD.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule (
    $IdentityReference,
    "Self",  # Access mask
    "Allow",
    "f3a64788-5306-11d1-a9c5-0000f80367c1",  # GUID for 'Validated write to service principal name'
    "None",
    [guid]::Empty
)))

# Write Account Restrictions
$SD.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule (
    $IdentityReference,
    "WriteProperty",  # Access mask
    "Allow",
    "4c164200-20c0-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529",  # GUID for 'Account Restrictions' PropertySet
    "None",
    [guid]::Empty
)))

# Reset password
$SD.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule (
    $IdentityReference,
    "ExtendedRight",  # Access mask
    "Allow", 
    "00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529",  # GUID for 'Reset Password' extended right
    "None",
    [guid]::Empty
)))

$SD | Set-Acl
```

Comment: Thanks - I will look at this.  Been too busy today.